# absolute positioned div over pdf in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf, safari

I'm currently working on a custom jquery menu that occasionally needs to hover over a pdf (embedded within an iframe). It is composed of absolute positioned divs that are shown on click/hover of it's parent.  Pretty simple.

Safari is giving me a headache.  I cannot figure out how to get the menu div to position over the pdf. It is always under. The timeless background iframe approach works great for IE, but fails for Safari (I've got Windows version 5.1.7).  This is a big problem.

I've racked my brain, scoured the web, thought about hiding the pdf, considered retiring, beaten my head against my desk... I'm at a loss!  Somebody's gotta know how to handle this.

Here's a simplified example that does what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/5WPa2/1/

HTML

```
<div id="divHover">try me</div>
<div id="divHoverChild">hello</div>
<iframe id="ifBG" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<iframe id="ifPDF" src="http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
#divHoverChild, #ifBG {
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    left: 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}

#divHoverChild {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#ifBG {
    z-index: 1;
    border:none;
}

#ifPDF {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

JS

```
$().ready(function () {
    var $child = $("#divHoverChild");
    var $ifBG = $("#ifBG");

    $("#divHover").mouseover(function () {
        $child.slideDown();
        $ifBG.slideDown();
    });

    $child.mouseout(function () {
        $child.slideUp();
        $ifBG.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you ever found solution to this problem ?

Comment: Rahul, I must admit it fell to the back burner for now but at last glance,  it was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the right syntax:

```
$().ready(function () {
    var $child = $("#divHoverChild");
    var $ifBG = $("#ifBG");

    $("#divHover").mouseover(function () {
        $child.slideDown();
        $ifBG.slideDown();
    });
    $("#divHoverChild").mouseout(function () {
        $child.slideUp();
        $ifBG.slideUp();
    });
});
```

You see, when you have your **divHoverChild** poped up it overflows the **divHover**, so when you move your mouse down out of **divHover** area , your jquery triggers the mouseout event on the **divHover** element, so then it slides up

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend using jQuery functions where you can manage it with css and html. There is an example of pretty good css/html menu structure with all transitions and other effects. http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/1992017. ( Tried with iframe, very responsive )

Comment: To alleviate confusion, I've updated the code.  That was a slight oversight in haste to get a small example in the Q.  It was not taken from my actual code.

That being said, it has absolutely nothing to do with my problem. I'm looking for a solution to hovering a div over a pdf in Safari.

Comment: As for using pure css, of course that would be ideal, but it will not facilitate my requirements and would not address my issue either. :-(